# appengine 1.6.3.1.jar creates Unknown Google App Engine prob

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt2

I was using appengine-java-sdk 1.5.3.
My web application Project was working fine.

I configured the Sdk and add new sdk 1.6.3

I got many errors in Problem window.

```
The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.3.1.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib
directory   lib /project/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem

The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-api-labs-1.6.3.1.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib 
directory   lib /project/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem

The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-jsr107cache-1.6.3.1.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib
directory   lib /project/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem

The App Engine SDK JAR datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar is missing in the WEB-F/lib 
directory   lib /project/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem
```

I tried to find these Jar file.but i didnt see them any where.

someone plz help me to solve this.

Comment: Looks like your are using the 1.6.3.1 version, did u download it? http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.3.1.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Eclipse --> Preferences --> Google --> App Engine  I had to point to a copy of the App Engine SDK that I had downloaded and installed locally on my computer as opposed to inside of an IDE.  Once I did this the errors about these libs not be in Web-Inf disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to clean your project. In eclipse,  Project -> Clean.